# React Native & Expo - onContextCreate function not calling when application ran

Tags: react-native, expo

I don't know why and there is no error shown in debugger-ui. I only see white screen in my iphone with no errors. I also add a console.log inside onContextCreate function and there is no message, so it means onContextCreate function not triggered and here is my code. Any help is very helpful.

```
import { View as GraphicsView } from 'expo-graphics';
import ExpoTHREE, { THREE } from 'expo-three';
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    THREE.suppressExpoWarnings();
  }

  render() {
    // Create an `ExpoGraphics.View` covering the whole screen, tell it to call our
    // `onContextCreate` function once it's initialized.
    return (
      <GraphicsView
        style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
        onContextCreate={this.onContextCreate}
        onRender={this.onRender}
      />
    );
  }

  // This is called by the `ExpoGraphics.View` once it's initialized
  onContextCreate = async ({
    gl,
    canvas,
    width,
    height,
    scale: pixelRatio,
  }) => {

    console.log('onContextCreate ran...');

    this.renderer = new ExpoTHREE.Renderer({ gl, pixelRatio, width, height });
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff)
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.z = 5;
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);

    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000,
    });
    
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(this.cube);

    this.scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040));

    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    light.position.set(3, 3, 3);
    this.scene.add(light);
  };

  onRender = delta => {
    this.cube.rotation.x += 3.5 * delta;
    this.cube.rotation.y += 2 * delta;
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that when i close remote debugger in EXPO than my codes are working. This is why happened i don't know. It is good to someone else explain it but it works when i close remote debugging in EXPO...